# Which cable should be used in paired AUX sends and return on mixer?

Tags: mixer, digital, spdif, aux-sends

My mixer has paired aux send and return jacks. For example aux 1/2 send and return are SPDIF, and the 3/4, 5/6 aux send and return jacks are paired. There are not separate aux send and return jacks. How do I use these to connect effects units.

What type of cable would I use? Is a Y cable the same as an insert cable?

Can someone explain how to use these paired aux send and return jacks, and the proper cables needed to hook a a mono loop and a stereo loop. Can someone explain it as if I was a beginner and knew nothing about mixers.

Comment: Hi! Maybe if you told us what mixer model you have, it would be a bit easier to help you ;) Because on some stereo mixers, the aux is mono, and on some, it can be stereo. Insert is mono always since you need a TRS (3-wire) cable for that: IN, OUT and GND.

Comment: Y-cables are used for insert jacks.  Checkout out [this](http://sound.stackexchange.com/q/24665/6957) answer I wrote for a previous question.

Answer (score 1):

The send is (probably) the Tip and return (probably) the Ring on on TRS splitter cable, something like this: http://www.swamp.net.au/swamp-insert-cable-y-cable-trs-to-2x-ts-1m.html

Answer (score 0):

No, a Y cable is not the same as an insert cable.  An L/R split cable however may be depending on the pinout used for the insert.  A y splitter cable generally sends a tip and sleeve signal to the tip and sleeve of two different jacks.  An insert cable will have a tip/ring/sleeve connector that goes in to the board and then will have two tip/sleeve jacks that are wired up according to which parts are ground and which parts are the send and return on the insert.